# jQuery: getPos for my drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a jQuery drop-down menu, but usable anywhere on my page. I would like it to be dynamic (as each element that contains the trigger class and that it is positioned perfectly). To do this, I need to have a jQuery code that replace my drop-down with the element clicked like this example (at the center of the clicked text): http://prntscr.com/7hw91t on this site: https://www.invisionpower.com/

My **HTML** code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="more">
        <a href="#" class="drop-down-menu-trigger">More</a>
    </li>
    <li class="more">
        <a href="#" class="drop-down-menu-trigger">Second Menu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code is referred to the elements that, when clicked, will open the drop-down: http://prntscr.com/7hwa7m The "`drop-down-menu-trigger`" is the class that will trigger the opening of the drop-down menu.

This is the drop-down-menu code that is placed at the bottom of my index.php:

```
    <div id="more-drop-down-menu" class="drop-down-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="modal-window-trigger" name="modal-window-faq" id="faq" href="faq.php">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="faq.php">Test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my **JS** code:

```
(function($)
{
    $(".drop-down-menu-trigger").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".drop-down-menu").css({"visibility": "visible"});
    });
})(jQuery);
```

my **CSS**:

```
.drop-down-menu
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 188px;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 110px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.drop-down-menu:before
{
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 100%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.drop-down-menu a
{
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}

.drop-down-menu a:hover
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

I would like to have help for this, so thanks to those who will try to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like this but not tested, you should put or render what you have in jsfiddler so we can see what your after.

```
(function($)
{
    $(".drop-down-menu-trigger").click(function(e)
    {
         e.preventDefault();

        //get location offset css
       var leftPos = $(this).offset().left,
            topPos = $(this).offset().top;

       $(".drop-down-menu").css({
           "visibility": "visible",
           "left": leftPos,
           "top": topPos
           });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

## Updated Answer :

There was several changes which included CSS and some offset in jquery for getting the carret to the middle off the menu, here is the updated version on fiddler

http://jsfiddle.net/screepts/rh2w16of/2/

here is the screenshot of updated code working with your menu

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code, but it does not work as I want. You can have a live preview of my full code here: http://nextgenfocus.com/code/

Comment: okay i will update my answer in jsfiddler due to needing to change some css

Comment: Thanks. :) The idea is to have like on this site: https://www.invisionpower.com/ You can see the drop-down is perfectly aligned with the clicked element: http://prntscr.com/7hxkzt

Comment: Nice, but it is possible to calculate the middle of each clicked element? Look this: http://prntscr.com/7hxois I'd like that the drop-down is perfectly aligned in the middle of the text like that: http://prntscr.com/7hxooj  Something automatic for any length of text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80754/discussion-between-luke-hardiman-and-uptop-14).